# Tapping a specific element by it's label or identifier that has the same name as other labels - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, automation, automated-tests, label

I'm trying to tap an element that has the same label and identifier as other labels. For example, I have `app.otherElements["TEST"].tap()` to tap the first element with the label `TEST`. However there is another element with the same exact label that I want to tap.

I know you can do `app.otherElements(boundBy: 1).tap()` to tap the next available `Other` element however I want to target labels specifically or even identifiers.

Is there any method to do this in Swift?

Comment: give them different identifiers, if something is not unique you can not target it uniquely